# Is there an option to smooth those segmented lines in Visio 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio-2013

[image: Line-Curve Connector in Visio 2007]

[image: Line-Curve Connector in Visio 2013]

When I open a Visio 2007 Document or I create a new Document in Visio 2013 the Line-Curve Connector is shown as several segmented lines instead of real curve lines as was done in Visio 2003 - 2007. All my documents were done with the Line-Curve connector, is there an option to smooth those segmented lines?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following to smoothen the line:

File -> Options -> Advanced -> Free-form Drawing -> Smoothening Slider

Slide the smoothening slider to middle to reduce the points, it will automatically smoothen the spline.